# Pandas - Event separation - .iloc iteritem()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample_data.txt with structure.

```
Precision= Waterdrops

2009-11-17 14:00:00,4.9,
2009-11-17 14:30:00,6.1,
2009-11-17 15:00:00,5.3,
2009-11-17 15:30:00,3.3,
2009-11-17 16:00:00,4.9,
```

I need to separate my data with the values bigger than zero and identify change (event) with timespam bigger than  2 h. So far i have wrote:

```
file_path  = 'sample_data.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skiprows = [num for (num,line) in enumerate(open(file_path),2) if 'Precision=' in line][0],
                 parse_dates =  True,index_col = 0,header= None, sep =',',
                 names = ['meteo', 'empty'])
df['date'] = df.index
df = df.drop(['empty'], axis=1)
df = df[df.meteo>20]
df['diff'] = df.date-df.date.shift(1)
df['sections'] = (diff > np.timedelta64(2, "h")).astype(int).cumsum()
```

From the above code i get:

```
                   meteo    date                diff       sections
2009-12-15 12:00:00 23.8    2009-12-15 12:00:00 NaT         0
2009-12-15 13:00:00 23.0    2009-12-15 13:00:00 01:00:00    0
```

If i use:

```
df.date.iloc[[0, -1]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

I get:

```
0   2009-12-15 12:00:00
1   2012-12-05 16:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Which is the start date and finish date of my example_data.txt.

How i can get .iloc[[0, -1]].reset_index(drop=True) for each df['section'] category ?

I tried with .apply:

```
def f(s):
    return s.iloc[[0, -1]].reset_index(drop=True)

df.groupby(df['sections']).apply(f)
```

and i get: IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use the `drop_index()` shenanigans. My somewhat more straightforward process would be, starting with

```
df

   sections       meteo      date      diff
0         0  2009-12-15  12:00:00       NaT
1         0  2009-12-15  13:00:00  01:00:00
0         1  2009-12-15  12:00:00       NaT
1         1  2009-12-15  13:00:00  01:00:00
```

to do (after you ensure with `sort('sections', 'date')` that `iloc[0,-1]` actually is start and end, otherwise just use `min()` and `max()` )

```
def f(s):
    return s.iloc[[0, -1]]['date']
df.groupby('sections').apply(f)

date             0         1
sections                    
0         12:00:00  13:00:00
1         12:00:00  13:00:00
```

Or, as a more streamlined approach

```
df.groupby('sections')['date'].agg([np.max, np.min])
              amax      amin
sections                    
0         13:00:00  12:00:00
1         13:00:00  12:00:00
```